# Heroku Deployment Continues to Fail at "Pruning devDependencies" Step

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, npm

I continue to have issues deploying to Heroku and I can't find out what is going wrong for the life of me. The Heroku error log tells me this after it successfully builds my react app:

```
-----> Caching build
       - node_modules

-----> Pruning devDependencies
       npm ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "homepage": "./",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "server.js",
  "node": "v12.13.1",
  "npm": "6.13.7",
  "scripts": {
    "heroku": "node server.js",
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "build": "cd client && react-scripts build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "John Doe",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.8.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "concurrently": "^5.1.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.8.1",
    "debug": "^4.1.1",
    "depcheck": "^0.9.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^4.6.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "fibers": "^4.0.2",
    "growl": "^1.10.5",
    "heroku": "^7.35.1",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "is-empty": "^1.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "material-table": "^1.54.2",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.2",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.4",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.9",
    "mongoose-global": "^1.0.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "plaid": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-ga": "^2.7.0",
    "react-plaid-link-button": "0.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.25.2",
    "react-stripe-elements": "^6.0.1",
    "react-vis": "^1.11.7",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sass": "^1.24.0",
    "slick": "^1.12.2",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4",
    "update-mongo": "0.0.4",
    "validator": "^12.2.0",
    "vis": "^4.21.0-EOL"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.x"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

What is perhaps most frustrating, is that I was able to deploy successfully once the other day but I am not sure what changed. Going back through my git I can't see anything that would have made any difference.

Things I have tried:

- removing package.json
- adding `"devDependencies": {}` to my    package.json (although I
  deployed successfully without it)
- updating node and adding the `engines` section to my package.json to
  match.
- running npm prune locally
- ensuring that all packages are updated and referenced appropriately in package.json

Things that I suspect could be the issue:

- Maybe somehow the current version of my app that is actively deployed on heroku is interfering with my new deployment? That being said i have tried scaling down dynos and deploying. Additionally the `npm ERR! Cannot read property 'match' of undefined` seems to indicate something else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just run into this after my deploys inexplicably started failing after a number of successful ones.

Stopping heroku from caching `node_modules` seemed to do the trick for me.

`heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false`

Then `git push heroku master`

I don't have `package-lock.json` committed after hearing Heroku doesn't get on well with lockfiles, but wondering if that's the problem.

Comment: dude.. this just saved me so much time and effort. i cannot thank you enough. setting that config variable to false solved it for me.

Comment: As a separate question, I am able to navigate to the heroku app on my browser, however just on my local machine (I can't open it on my phone or on the same browser on a different laptop). Any idea why this might be? I'm just using Hobby dynos so maybe I need to scale up? I might also need to scale up my MongoDB backend (currently using the free version) or perhaps my build could be optimized a bit better... Sorry for the abstract follow-up!

Comment: Glad it helped - regarding not being able to hit your app, I'm not too sure about that. I'm on hobby dynos myself as well, but both my front end and backend dynos can be accessed from anywhere.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me as well! I just wanted to add that you can simply go to your environment variables from the settings tab in the heroku app dashboard and add the key/value pair `NODE_MODULES_CACHE` : `false` as an alternative to the cli option or in the start script. I experienced the same issue where my build was succeeding previously and then for no apparent reason it started failing with the match undefined error. Thanks again for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please `rm -rf node_modules && npm i`
also be sure to track `package-lock.json` file

And as long as you are there, is not related but may be a good idea to add a `.nvmrc` file

`node -v >> .nvmrc`

Let us know if it helped

Answer (score -1):

In the `scripts` section in `package.json`, only keep the `start` key and remove others.

Your `scripts` in the `package.json` should be,

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
```

Also before deployment, build the react app manually.

Heroku messed up with all these `build` scripts.

Comment: I tried Mike's answer below and that solved my issue. Thank you for your answer though!